# Getting an eof error during large sql queries

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

We have a production MySQL 5.7 database running in AWS RDS. Some of our users are trying to pull down very large queries that involve multiple UNIONS and recently have started to get the following error:

> Unexpected EOF found when reading file '/rdsdbdata/tmp/MYpPkaJx'
> (Errcode: 175 - File to short; Expected more data in file)

My understanding is that the temporary table(s) the database is forced to use because of the UNION are unable to contain all of the data. Though admittedly my understanding is pretty flawed with regard to temporary tables and teh variables that control them.

Here is the output of an EXPLAIN ran on the primary query that is failing. As you can likely guess the query is grossly overcomplicated but I'd rather just crank up whatever variables are necessary to handle the temp table sizes than dive into our users query here and figure out a way to improve it:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | ts | \0 | ALL | TradeTime | TradeTime_ProductSymbol | \0 | \0 | \0 | 9990635 | 50.00 |
| 3 | DERIVED | tl | \0 | ALL | TradeTime | TradeTime_ProductSymbol | \0 | \0 | \0 | 2120131 | 14.17 |
| 4 | UNION | ts | \0 | ALL | TradeTime | TradeTime_ProductSymbol | \0 | \0 | \0 | 9539112 | 48.66 |
| 6 | DERIVED | tl | \0 | ALL | TradeTime | TradeTime_ProductSymbol | \0 | \0 | \0 | 1263645 | 14.81 |
| 7 | UNION | ts | \0 | ALL | TradeTime | TradeTime_ProductSymbol | \0 | \0 | \0 | 166392106 | 50.00 |
| 9 | DERIVED | tl | \0 | ALL | TradeTime | TradeTime_ProductSymbol | \0 | \0 | \0 | 1884188 | 14.81 |
| 10 | UNION | ts | \0 | ALL | TradeTime | TradeTime_ProductSymbol | \0 | \0 | \0 | 582313 | 50.00 |
| 12 | DERIVED | tl | \0 | ALL | TradeTime | TradeTime_ProductSymbol | \0 | \0 | \0 | 602768 | 14.81 |
| 13 | UNION | ts | \0 | ALL | TradeTime | TradeTime_ProductSymbol | \0 | \0 | \0 | 1694557 | 50.00 |
| 15 | DERIVED | tl | \0 | ALL | TradeTime | TradeTime_ProductSymbol | \0 | \0 | \0 | 200808 | 14.13 |
| 16 | UNION | ts | \0 | ALL | TradeTime | TradeTime_ProductSymbol | \0 | \0 | \0 | 4389286 | 50.00 |
| 18 | DERIVED | tl | \0 | ALL | TradeTime | TradeTime_ProductSymbol | \0 | \0 | \0 | 111854 | 14.81 |
| 19 | UNION | ts | \0 | ALL | TradeTime | TradeTime_ProductSymbol | \0 | \0 | \0 | 17966978 | 50.00 |
| 21 | DERIVED | tl | \0 | ALL | TradeTime | TradeTime_ProductSymbol | \0 | \0 | \0 | 66698 | 14.81 |
| \0 | UNION RESULT | <union1 | 4 | 7 | 10 | 13 | 16 | 19> | \0 | ALL | \0 | \0 | \0 | Using temporary |
| 1 | PRIMARY | spt | \0 | eq_ref | TimeSalesID | TimeSalesID | 4 | t1.ts.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 1 | PRIMARY | sptg | \0 | eq_ref | TimeSalesID | TimeSalesID | 4 | t1.ts.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 3 | DERIVED | sp | \0 | eq_ref | TradeLogID | TradeLogID | 4 | t1.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 3 | DERIVED | spg | \0 | eq_ref | TradeLogID | TradeLogID | 4 | t1.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 3 | DERIVED | tq | \0 | eq_ref | FK_tradelog_quoterfields_tradelog | FK_tradelog_quoterfields_tradelog | 4 | t1.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 3 | DERIVED | tls | \0 | eq_ref | FK_tradelog_slippage_tradelog | FK_tradelog_slippage_tradelog | 4 | t1.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 4 | UNION | spt | \0 | eq_ref | TimeSalesID | TimeSalesID | 4 | t2.ts.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 4 | UNION | sptg | \0 | eq_ref | TimeSalesID | TimeSalesID | 4 | t2.ts.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 6 | DERIVED | sp | \0 | eq_ref | TradeLogID | TradeLogID | 4 | t2.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 6 | DERIVED | spg | \0 | eq_ref | TradeLogID | TradeLogID | 4 | t2.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 6 | DERIVED | tls | \0 | eq_ref | FK_tradelog_slippage_tradelog | FK_tradelog_slippage_tradelog | 4 | t2.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 7 | UNION | spt | \0 | eq_ref | TimeSalesID | TimeSalesID | 4 | eminis.ts.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 7 | UNION | sptg | \0 | eq_ref | TimeSalesID | TimeSalesID | 4 | eminis.ts.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 9 | DERIVED | sp | \0 | eq_ref | TradeLogID | TradeLogID | 4 | eminis.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 9 | DERIVED | spg | \0 | eq_ref | TradeLogID | TradeLogID | 4 | eminis.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 9 | DERIVED | tls | \0 | eq_ref | FK_tradelog_slippage_tradelog | FK_tradelog_slippage_tradelog | 4 | eminis.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 10 | UNION | spt | \0 | eq_ref | TimeSalesID | TimeSalesID | 4 | eurodollars.ts.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 10 | UNION | sptg | \0 | eq_ref | TimeSalesID | TimeSalesID | 4 | eurodollars.ts.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 12 | DERIVED | sp | \0 | eq_ref | TradeLogID | TradeLogID | 4 | eurodollars.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 12 | DERIVED | spg | \0 | eq_ref | TradeLogID | TradeLogID | 4 | eurodollars.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 12 | DERIVED | tls | \0 | eq_ref | FK_tradelog_slippage_tradelog | FK_tradelog_slippage_tradelog | 4 | eurodollars.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 13 | UNION | spt | \0 | eq_ref | TimeSalesID | TimeSalesID | 4 | natgas.ts.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 13 | UNION | sptg | \0 | eq_ref | TimeSalesID | TimeSalesID | 4 | natgas.ts.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 15 | DERIVED | sp | \0 | eq_ref | TradeLogID | TradeLogID | 4 | natgas.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 15 | DERIVED | spg | \0 | eq_ref | TradeLogID | TradeLogID | 4 | natgas.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 15 | DERIVED | tq | \0 | eq_ref | FK_tradelog_quoterfields_tradelog | FK_tradelog_quoterfields_tradelog | 4 | natgas.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 15 | DERIVED | tls | \0 | eq_ref | FK_tradelog_slippage_tradelog | FK_tradelog_slippage_tradelog | 4 | natgas.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 16 | UNION | spt | \0 | eq_ref | TimeSalesID | TimeSalesID | 4 | oil.ts.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 16 | UNION | sptg | \0 | eq_ref | TimeSalesID | TimeSalesID | 4 | oil.ts.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 18 | DERIVED | sp | \0 | eq_ref | TradeLogID | TradeLogID | 4 | oil.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 18 | DERIVED | spg | \0 | eq_ref | TradeLogID | TradeLogID | 4 | oil.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 18 | DERIVED | tq | \0 | eq_ref | FK_tradelog_quoterfields_tradelog | FK_tradelog_quoterfields_tradelog | 4 | oil.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 18 | DERIVED | tls | \0 | eq_ref | FK_tradelog_slippage_tradelog | FK_tradelog_slippage_tradelog | 4 | oil.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 19 | UNION | spt | \0 | eq_ref | TimeSalesID | TimeSalesID | 4 | eminis_zero.ts.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 19 | UNION | sptg | \0 | eq_ref | TimeSalesID | TimeSalesID | 4 | eminis_zero.ts.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 21 | DERIVED | sp | \0 | eq_ref | TradeLogID | TradeLogID | 4 | eminis_zero.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 21 | DERIVED | spg | \0 | eq_ref | TradeLogID | TradeLogID | 4 | eminis_zero.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 21 | DERIVED | tls | \0 | eq_ref | FK_tradelog_slippage_tradelog | FK_tradelog_slippage_tradelog | 4 | eminis_zero.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 2 | DERIVED | ins | \0 | index | InstrumentID_ExchangeSymbol | InstrumentID | IsMostRecent | ExchangeSymbol | InstrumentType | ExpirationDate | InstrumentID_ExchangeSymbol | \0 | 100.00 |
| 5 | DERIVED | ins | \0 | index | InstrumentID_ExchangeSymbol | InstrumentID | IsMostRecent | ExchangeSymbol | InstrumentType | ExpirationDate | InstrumentID_ExchangeSymbol | \0 | 100.00 |
| 8 | DERIVED | ins | \0 | index | InstrumentID_ExchangeSymbol | InstrumentID | IsMostRecent | ExchangeSymbol | InstrumentType | ExpirationDate | InstrumentID_ExchangeSymbol | \0 | 100.00 |
| 11 | DERIVED | ins | \0 | index | InstrumentID_ExchangeSymbol | InstrumentID | IsMostRecent | ExchangeSymbol | InstrumentType | ExpirationDate | InstrumentID_ExchangeSymbol | \0 | 100.00 |
| 14 | DERIVED | ins | \0 | index | InstrumentID_ExchangeSymbol | InstrumentID | IsMostRecent | ExchangeSymbol | InstrumentType | ExpirationDate | InstrumentID_ExchangeSymbol | \0 | 100.00 |
| 17 | DERIVED | ins | \0 | index | InstrumentID_ExchangeSymbol | InstrumentID | IsMostRecent | ExchangeSymbol | InstrumentType | ExpirationDate | InstrumentID_ExchangeSymbol | \0 | 100.00 |
| 20 | DERIVED | ins | \0 | index | InstrumentID_ExchangeSymbol | InstrumentID | IsMostRecent | ExchangeSymbol | InstrumentType | ExpirationDate | InstrumentID_ExchangeSymbol | \0 | 100.00 |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  | \0 | ref | <auto_key0> | <auto_key0> | 4 | t1.ts.InstrumentID | 10 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | tge | \0 | ref | TimesalesID | TimesalesID | 5 | t1.ts.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 1 | PRIMARY |  | \0 | ref | <auto_key0> | <auto_key0> | 61 | t1.ts.NanoSinceEpoch | t1.ts.InstrumentExchangeSymbol | 10 | 100.00 |
| 4 | UNION |  | \0 | ref | <auto_key0> | <auto_key0> | 4 | t2.ts.InstrumentID | 10 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 4 | UNION | tge | \0 | ref | TimesalesID | TimesalesID | 5 | t2.ts.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 4 | UNION |  | \0 | ref | <auto_key0> | <auto_key0> | 61 | t2.ts.NanoSinceEpoch | t2.ts.InstrumentExchangeSymbol | 10 | 100.00 |
| 6 | DERIVED | tq | \0 | ref | FK_tradelog_quoterfields_tradelog | FK_tradelog_quoterfields_tradelog | 4 | t2.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 7 | UNION |  | \0 | ref | <auto_key0> | <auto_key0> | 4 | eminis.ts.InstrumentID | 10 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 7 | UNION | tge | \0 | ref | TimesalesID | TimesalesID | 5 | eminis.ts.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 7 | UNION |  | \0 | ref | <auto_key0> | <auto_key0> | 61 | eminis.ts.NanoSinceEpoch | eminis.ts.InstrumentExchangeSymbol | 10 | 100.00 |
| 9 | DERIVED | tq | \0 | ref | FK_tradelog_quoterfields_tradelog | FK_tradelog_quoterfields_tradelog | 4 | eminis.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 10 | UNION |  | \0 | ref | <auto_key0> | <auto_key0> | 4 | eurodollars.ts.InstrumentID | 10 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 10 | UNION | tge | \0 | ref | TimesalesID | TimesalesID | 5 | eurodollars.ts.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 10 | UNION |  | \0 | ref | <auto_key0> | <auto_key0> | 61 | eurodollars.ts.NanoSinceEpoch | eurodollars.ts.InstrumentExchangeSymbol | 10 | 100.00 |
| 12 | DERIVED | tq | \0 | ref | FK_tradelog_quoterfields_tradelog | FK_tradelog_quoterfields_tradelog | 4 | eurodollars.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 13 | UNION |  | \0 | ref | <auto_key0> | <auto_key0> | 4 | natgas.ts.InstrumentID | 10 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 13 | UNION | tge | \0 | ref | TimesalesID | TimesalesID | 5 | natgas.ts.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 13 | UNION |  | \0 | ref | <auto_key0> | <auto_key0> | 61 | natgas.ts.NanoSinceEpoch | natgas.ts.InstrumentExchangeSymbol | 10 | 100.00 |
| 16 | UNION |  | \0 | ref | <auto_key0> | <auto_key0> | 4 | oil.ts.InstrumentID | 10 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 16 | UNION | tge | \0 | ref | TimesalesID | TimesalesID | 5 | oil.ts.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 16 | UNION |  | \0 | ref | <auto_key0> | <auto_key0> | 61 | oil.ts.NanoSinceEpoch | oil.ts.InstrumentExchangeSymbol | 10 | 100.00 |
| 19 | UNION |  | \0 | ref | <auto_key0> | <auto_key0> | 4 | eminis_zero.ts.InstrumentID | 10 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 19 | UNION | tge | \0 | ref | TimesalesID | TimesalesID | 5 | eminis_zero.ts.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
| 19 | UNION |  | \0 | ref | <auto_key0> | <auto_key0> | 61 | eminis_zero.ts.NanoSinceEpoch | eminis_zero.ts.InstrumentExchangeSymbol | 10 | 100.00 |
| 21 | DERIVED | tq | \0 | ref | FK_tradelog_quoterfields_tradelog | FK_tradelog_quoterfields_tradelog | 4 | eminis_zero.tl.ID | 1 | 100.00 | \0 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

All of the tables in the DB are Innodb and I have Innodb set as the engine for temp tables on disk. Here are the current buffer sizes in bytes

| Variable_name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| bulk_insert_buffer_size | 8388608 |
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size | 754974720 |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size | 96636764160 |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size | 25 |
| innodb_log_buffer_size | 4294966272 |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size | 67108864 |
| join_buffer_size | 4294967296 |
| key_buffer_size | 6442450944 |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size | 8388608 |
| preload_buffer_size | 32768 |
| read_buffer_size | 1610612736 |
| read_rnd_buffer_size | 2147479552 |
| sort_buffer_size | 4294967296 |

Comment: shot in the dark: could you be running out of disk space?  keep in mind, the disk might get filled very quickly, fail, and then immediately release the space on failure. also keep in mind that adding disk space in RDS is trivial, but removing that space definitely is *not*.

Comment: i'd suggest to >begin< with shooting the users writing these discusting queries because you have good odds to run into the next bottleneck (CPU load, IO throuput, IO wait etc.) as soon as you fixed the current one (maybe disk space). I don't think it makes much sense to force the db to somehow gulp these queries.
If the users can't write SQL, they need some training to form tons of UNIONs of the same table into proper WHERE clauses.